# Stacking V-Card children overlaps and misaligns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to stack a *v-card-title* on top of a *v-card-subtitle* and then *v-card-text* and the text is overlapping. Don't these elements vertically stack by default?:

```
<v-main>
  <v-container fluid style="padding:0px"> 
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col :cols="12" :md="6">

        <v-card 
           height='100%' 
           style="position: relative"
           elevation="0">

           <v-card-title
             class="header">
                  lorem ipsum dolor
           </v-card-title>

           <v-card-subtitle class="subHeader">
              lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor
           </v-card-subtitle>

           <v-card-text class="subText">
               lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum 
               dolor lorem ipsum dolor dolor lorem ipsum dolor dolor lorem ipsum 
               dolor
           </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
      <v-col :cols="12" :md="6">
        <v-img :src="{myImage}"></v-img>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    {...about 4 more rows identical to above...}
  </v-container>
</v-main>
```

and here are my styles:

```
.header{
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 85px;
  }
  .subHeader{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .subText{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    color:#333;
  }
```

and then if I try to vertically + horizontally center everything using this on the v-card, everything then lines up horizontally:

```
class="d-flex align-center justify-center"
```

What am I just not getting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `d-flex` turns your card into a flexbox container transforming direct children elements. What you're seeing is the default behavior of `flex` children. They display in a row because by default the `flex-direction` property is set to `row`. Read more at [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Anyway, you don't need to use `d-flex` in this case. Vuetify provides a helper class `fill-height` that will center the contents of the `v-container`. From the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#helper-classes):

> `fill-height` applies `height: 100%` to an element. When applied to `v-container` it will also `align-items: center`.

For example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid fill-height style="padding:0px">
        <v-row no-gutters justify=center>
          <v-col cols="6">
            <v-card class="" elevation="2" >
              <v-card-title class="header">
                lorem ipsum dolor
              </v-card-title>

              <v-card-subtitle class="subHeader">
                lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor
              </v-card-subtitle>

              <v-card-text class="subText">
                lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor dolor lorem ipsum dolor dolor lorem ipsum dolor
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've read the links you posted and understand flexbox better now. However, when I apply fill-height it's not doing the job of centering the content. So I updated my post with the surrounding elements of the V-Card because something there must be interfering. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: It seems like adding the "fluid" attribute to the container breaks it. If I remove it then it's horizontally centered, but not vertically.

Comment: Not sure why adding `fluid` breaks it on your end. I edited my answer and added `justify=center` property to center the card horizontally. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NeD8.png)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's working. I'll mark this answer as correct. Last thing -- how can I vertically center the card?

Comment: If I add a v-container with fill-height around each Card then it works great. I'm guessing it's not bad form to have multiple v-containers in an app -- is that true?

Comment: You should have only one `v-container`. Sound like you are very close but honestly, it's a little bit hard to understand what exactly is your issue right now :) Perhaps if you could create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/your-work) that would be easier to help you.

Comment: I really appreciate your help so much. I've never used codepen before so I'm not sure why I'm getting registration errors but i think i must be close. But here it is all the same. https://codepen.io/fumeng/pen/eYeVMZV

Comment: Ok - this one is at least compiling: https://codepen.io/fumeng/pen/xxPYjJO

Comment: Okay, I think I see where the confusion is coming from. You're setting the `max-width` of the image inside the second column, so it appears as if the whole thing is aligned to the left. In reality, the app is centered. Also, I think I understand now that you were trying to center vertically the contents of the cards in relation to the pictures. Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/olegnaumov/pen/NWwyzWm). Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, i see. you only added "align=center" to the row and that works because the flex-direction is row so the cross-axis is the column. and align=center will align to that cross-axis. do i have it right?

Comment: I believe you're correct :)